# Error after metro bundle in React native android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

**in Ios it's working and when i tried to run in android error comes and stuck at splashscreen**

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js 

 ERROR  Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

**Tried multiple solution like upgrading the firebase dependencies and versions still getting error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are invoking the App before the Firebase has been initialised. You should have in the ./index.js file

- firebase.initializeApp(config);
- var db = firebase.firestore();

Please note, this is just the example and instead use meaningful variable naming convention.